# How to call JQuery Ajax Post with querystring URL

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a web page which is redirected from a another page and have a querystring in it. now this page is calling a Jquery AJAX call to do some other task.

Page URL is like : http://localhost:1041/Inventory/Inventorydetail.aspx?invoiceid=3

now this page is calling a AJAX post to delete a record from the grid.

```
           $(".DeleteInvoiceLine").click(function() {
             //Get the Id of the record
             var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
             var loc = window.location;
             // Ask user's confirmation
             if (confirm("Do you want to delete this record?")) {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: loc + "/DeleteInvoiceLineEntry",
                     //Pass the selected record id
                     data: "{'args': '" + record_id + "'}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function(msgstr) {
                      var msg = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_success");
                      msg.html(msgstr.d);
                      msg.show();

                     }
                 });
             }
             return false;
         });
```

so when I call the AJAX call the page_Load event is called instead of the webmethod "DeleteInvoiceLineEntry".

if I have my page without the querystring passed it works fine.

could you please suggest me how I can call a AJAX call on the page which has a querystring data init.

I tried it both way passing the static URL 
Not working 
  url: "Inventorydetail.aspx?invoiceid=3/DeleteInvoiceLineEntry"

Working (if there is no querystring data in the page)

url: "Inventorydetail.aspx/DeleteInvoiceLineEntry"

Thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach query string when you call ajax. It will confuse the communication as ajax actually use query string to pass json data. If you want to pass invoiceid to the ajax, include it in json data.

Comment: Sheen, there are two things here. one is InvoiceID and second one is InvoiceLineID.the InvoiceID is passed in query string from another page to fill the invoiceData in the grid and the InvoiceLineId is passed in the JSON data in the Ajax call when user delete the row(InvoiceLine) from the grid. So my question is here how I can call the ajax post if the page is already having a querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var loc = window.location;
```

To

```
var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search, '');
```

as Taesung Shin mentioned. The query string in the URL is confusing your application.